# Does SharePoint create O365 group for a MS Teams Channel created SharePoint Site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, team-sites, microsoft-teams, office-365-groups

I have created a Teams Channel and thus can see a SharePoint teams site has been created. Wanted to verify, if the SP site has created any kind of O365 group by default while provisioning the SP site through teams channel creation?

If Yes, where I can find the same and Can I add members directly to that O365 group and provision permission to that group within the SP site?

Please guide me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, Microsoft 365 group is created only when you create a "team" in Microsoft Teams or when you create a team site connected with M365 group from SharePoint.

Separate M365 group is not created for "each" channel created inside the "team" in Microsoft teams.

To understand this, you will first have to understand the different types of channels available in Microsoft teams. Private and Shared Channels have their own SharePoint site for but not the Standard channels:

[image]

Read detailed information in below Microsoft official documentations:

1. [Overview of Teams and SharePoint integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/teams-connected-sites?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)
2. [Manage settings and permissions when SharePoint and Teams are integrated](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/manage-teams-sharepoint-experiences?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)
3. [Microsoft 365 Groups and Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/microsoftteams/office-365-groups?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)
4. [Learn about Microsoft 365 Groups](https://support.microsoft.com/office/learn-about-microsoft-365-groups-b565caa1-5c40-40ef-9915-60fdb2d97fa2?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)

---

If you have admin access in your Microsoft 365 portal, you can see the M365 groups in Admin center. You can open the groups page in M365 admin center directly using this URL: [M365 Admin Center - Groups](https://admin.microsoft.com/adminportal/home?#/groups?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)

[image]

---

If your SharePoint site is connected to M365 group, you can add members to site & group directly from your SharePoint site as well. Go to home page of your SharePoint site (connected with teams/M365 group) and click "Members" option:

[image]

It will open a "Group membership" panel where you can add users as group member or owner.